# Найти число, повторяющееся в массиве макс. кол. раз

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Задача - найти число в массиве, которое повторяется макс. кол-во раз. Если несколько чисел повторяются с одинаковой последовательностью - вывести их в порядке возрастания.

Ввод в консоль

```
5
2 3 3 3 2
```

Вывод

```
3
```

Число 3 повторяется макс. кол. раз.

Использую такой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main_class {

    static int num;
    static int[] features;
    static int temp = 0;
    static int result;
    static int[] resTable;


    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        num = sc.nextInt();
        features = new int[num];

        for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
            features[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        int c=0;
        for(int i = 0; i<features.length;i++){
            int freq = checkFreq(features[i]);
            if(freq>temp){
                temp=freq;
                result = features[i];
            } 


        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }

    public static int checkFreq (int res){
        int c =0;
        for(int i =0;i<features.length;i++){
            if(res==features[i]){
                c++;
            }
        }
        return c;



    }
}
```

Все хорошо работает в случае если в массиве только одно число повторяется большее кол-во раз.  Как можно сделать вывод в случае если ввод будет такой:

```
5
2 2 1 1 3
```

Мы должны получить

```
1 2
```

(в порядке возрастания)

Спасибо за ответы и советы!
P.s нельзя использовать НИЧЕГО кроме Сканнера

Comment: Рассортируйте массив (одинаковые числа окажутся рядом). Найдите индекс начала и длину максимально длинной последовательности одинаковых чисел. Напечатайте первое число из нее. Начиная с ее конца определяйте очередную последовательность и если ее длина равна максимальной, печатайте число из нее.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
int[] numbers = {2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 6, 7, 7, 2};
Arrays.sort(numbers);

int maxCount = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int prevNumber = numbers[0];
int currentCount = 0;

Set<Integer> results = new HashSet<>();

for (int num : numbers)
    if (prevNumber == num)
        currentCount++;
    else {
        maxCount = Math.max(currentCount, maxCount);
        if (maxCount == currentCount)
            results.add(prevNumber);

        prevNumber = num;
        currentCount = 1;
    }

System.out.println(maxCount);
System.out.println(results);
```

Вывод:

> 3
>   [1, 2]

Ps. если важна оптимальная асимптотическая сложность, то этот вариант не подойдет. Время его работы `O(n*log(n))`, подозреваю, что эту задачу можно решить за линейное время, но код был бы более громоздким.

Comment: Нельзя использовать НИЧЕГО кроме java.util.Scanner

Comment: @MDobroch  ну ок, напишите свою реализацию для метода sort, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

> Нельзя использовать НИЧЕГО кроме java.util.Scanner

Тогда можно записать повторения в еще один массив или даже в строку (но в массив как то правильней)

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    //входной массив
    int features[] = { 2, 2, 11, 11, 7, 6, 6, 8, 7, 7 };
    //массив с повторениями
    int reps[] = new int[features.length/2];
    
    int temp = features[0];
    //кол-во повторений temp
    int c = 0;
    //макс кол-во повторений во features
    int maxCount = 0;
    //index для записи в массив reps
    int r = 0;

    //записываем массив
    for(int i = 1; i < features.length + 1; i++) {
        //сделано для проверки последнего эл, оттуда и условие i < features.length + 1
        int cur = features.length > i ? features[i] : -features[i-1];
        if(cur == temp) {
            c++;
        } else {
          if (maxCount < c) {
              maxCount = c;
              r = 0;
              reps = new int[features.length/2];
              reps[r] = temp;
          } else if(maxCount == c) {
              r++;
              reps[r] = temp;
          }
          c = 0;
        }
        temp = cur;
    }
    //обрезаем в новый массив
    int result[] = new int[r+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < r + 1; i++) {
        result[i] = reps[i];
    }
    //выводим сортированный массив
    for (int k : sort(result)) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}

//сортируем по возрастанию
public static int[] sort (int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                int sTemp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = sTemp;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Результат ([onecompiler для проверки](https://onecompiler.com/java/3wa49zkhj)) для `{ 2, 2, 11, 11, 7, 6, 6, 8, 7, 7 }` будет

```
2
6
7
11
```

---

Если нужно число которое **встречается** макс. кол-во раз, тогда после заполнения `features` сортируем его `features = sort(features);`

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int[] features = new int[num];

    for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
        features[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }  
    
    int[] occurs = new int[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {  //Считаем склоко каждое число встречалось до этого
        for (int j = i-1; j >=0; j--) {
            if (features[j] == features[i]) {
                occurs[i] = occurs[j]+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {  //Сортируем "пузырьком"
        for (int j = 0; j < features.length-1; j++) {
            if (occurs[j] < occurs[j + 1] || (occurs[j] == occurs[j + 1] && features[j] > features[j + 1])) {
                int t = occurs[j]; occurs[j] = occurs[j + 1]; occurs[j + 1] = t;
                t = features[j]; features[j] = features[j + 1]; features[j + 1] = t;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    System.out.print(features[i]);
    while (occurs[i] == occurs[i+1] && i < num-1) {  //Выводим пока количество = максимальному
        i++;
        System.out.print(" "+features[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]